# NULL-вой указатель при открытии файла

Tags: c

В чём может заключаться ошибка при открытии файла.Путь к файлу прописал и проверил несколько раз:

```
FILE* fp;
    char words[MAX] = { 0 };
    fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\Elvin\\Desktop\\lol.txt", "a+");
    if (fp == NULL);
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "unable to open up the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

указатель почему-то всегда равен NULL.Почему возникают ошибки подобного рода ?

Comment: На то нам и дана переменная `errno`, чтоб узнать, что же именно произошло. Чему равно ее значение в вашем случае?

Comment: @Harry,у меня нет переменной errno, типо stderr ?

Comment: Ну да, в стандарте есть, а у вас нет? :) https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno

Comment: @Harry, а где её нужно поставить ?

Comment: Знаете, у меня подозрение, что у вас все нормально, и что точка с запятой после `(fp == NULL)` у вас не очепятка при переносе, а так и есть в исходнике... и вам **кажется**, что файл не открыт :)

Comment: Вы бы включили предупреждения в настройках компилятора. Тогда он бы вас сразу в эту `;` ткнул носом. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, а как это предупреждение включить ?

Comment: От компилятора зависит. У вас какой? И какая среда?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat,Win10,Microsoft visual studio 2017

Comment: У меня студия не стоит. Или гуглить, или ждать, пока подскажет кто-то, у кого она есть...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте выполнить такой фрагмент - что будет выведено?

```
FILE* fp;
char words[MAX] = { 0 };
fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\Elvin\\Desktop\\lol.txt", "a+");
if (fp == NULL)
{
    perror("File opening failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

P.S. Надеюсь, точка с запятой после `(fp == NULL)` у вас - опечатка?
P.P.S. В любом случае - чтобы узнать подробнее об ошибке при открытии файла, можно использовать значение переменной `errno`, или, например, функцию `perror`, которая выводит соответствующее "человеческое" сообщение.

Comment: ,действительно, я целый час над этим голову ломал, да , точка с запятой была, а что такое  perror и переменная errno ?А какое сообщение ,например,может быть выведено ?

Comment: А вы попробуйте открыть несуществующий файл, или открыть на запись файл с атрибутом read-only или еще что - и посмотрите. Программирование - наука экспериментальная! :)

Comment: Программирование — это не наука.

Comment: @0andriy Несомненно - по крайней мере для вас :)

Answer (score 1):

На вопрос автора как включить предупреждения в MSVC покажу картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]